# Understanding a proof of Wedderburn's little theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

I am working on the proof of Wedderburn theorem and I have a problem to understand the part of it. I don't understand why $b_{1}^{-1}a_{1}=\lambda^{i}$ implies the last contradiction $a_{1}b_{1}=b_{1}a_{1}$ and what for the equation $(a^{-1}b)^{r}=1$ was proved? Could anyone elaborate on this, please?

[image]

Thank you :)

Source: http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/articles_et_extraits_livres/Herstein-Wedderburn.pdf

Comment: I haven't read it in detail, but I think he says earlier that $\lambda \in Z$, so that $b_1^{-1} a_1 = \lambda^i \in Z$, so that $b_1^{-1} a_1 b_1 = b_1 b_1^{-1} a_1 = a_1$, so that $a_1 b_1 = b_1 a_1$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_1$ and $\lambda$ are both powers of $a$, so commute, so $$a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1=\lambda^ia_1^{-1}=b_1^{-1}.$$