# Finite Division Rings are Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

I have seen a problem recently. It says that every finite division ring is a field. How to show this?

Comment: Sometimes called [Wedderburn's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614634/division-rings-and-division-algebras.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That references proofs. I am not sure it gives one. Just looked more carefully. egreg's answer is not that helpful unless you know a fair amount of algebra.

Comment: This is a famous result and quite hard to prove. A condensed proof is still a page. A good, easy to understand one, is in  the Aigner and Ziegler book "Proofs from the book". It is certainly in the 3rd and 4th editions.

Comment: A scan of a proof [is available at this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/485667/29335).